# Odoo 9 installation on windows server 2008 or 2012

Tags: installation, odoo, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2, odoo-9

I am wondering if it is possible to install Odoo 9 on windows server 2008 or 2012 easily like what happens on windows 7. Any Idea please?

Comment: Did you run into problems when you tried it?...have you tried it at all?

Comment: I am forcing my company to buy a server specifically for Odoo. I want to be sure that there won't be any problem. I've not tried it. How is it?

Comment: Oh!...Odoo works best on Linux not on windows for example Multiprocessing mode is not available on windows (and i don't think there's any plan for that) and it's also easier to install on Linux and find help if you get stuck with something. So you should be going for a Linux server instead...Read this https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/setup/deploy.html

Comment: Also this question isn't a good fit for stackoverflow, because it's not about programming. so it would be best to close it...before you get hit by a stream of downvoters :)